# Adding & removing elements in vector of maps in clojure

Tags: vector, clojure, updates

I have a use case to implement in my hobby project where i would need to add and remove elements in vector of maps, items, based on some criteria like below

Below following are the input data structures used in my code

Items is a LazySeq

```
[
{
:name “Bananas”
:line-no 0
:quantity 4
}
{
:name “Apple”
:line-no 2
:quantity 3
}
]
```

return-quantities is a PersistentArrayMap with line-no as the key like below

```
{
2 1
}
```

My objective is to obtain a resultant vector with items split based on return-quantities

```
[
{
:name “Bananas”
:line-no 0
:quantity 4
}
{
:name “Apple”
:line-no 2
:quantity 1
:returned? true
}
{
:name “Apple”
:line-no 2
:quantity 2
}
]
```

Below is my example code which achieves that

```
(let [items-to-be-added
      (for [[line-no return-quantity] return-quantities]
        (let [item (seek #(= line-no (:line-no %)) items)
              item-quantity (:quantity item)
              regular-item (when (pos? (- item-quantity return-quantity))
                             (assoc item :quantity (- item-quantity rma-quantity))
                             (assoc item :return-item? true))
              returned-item (assoc item :quantity rma-quantity)
              result [regular-item returned-item]]
          result))
      items-to-be-removed
      (for [[line-no] return-quantities]
        (let [item (seek #(= line-no (:line-no %)) items)]
          item))
      items-updated (filterv #(not (contains? (vec items-to-be-removed) %)) (vec items))]
  (doall (flatten (concat items-updated items-to-be-added))))
```

The problem with the above code is that filtering (removing set of elements from vector) does not work. Can someone help me fix the issue with vector filtering ? Also can someone help me to achieve this with more efficient code as i feel that the impl is convoluted ?

Comment: Can you clarify what `2 : 1` means?  Also, your desired output is unclear. And, what is `seek`?

Comment: its a map with key as 2 and value 1 ? in the context of my question , it means for line no 2 returned quantity is 1 @AlanThompson

Comment: I have got the filtering working by using set. Is there some way i can get the code more efficient and better as it seems convoluted ? @AlanThompson in other words can i implement it with less code and more efficiently ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mapcat` when processing a collection to produce zero or more output elements for each input element:

```clj
(defn split-item [item quantity]
  (if quantity
    [(assoc item :returned? true :quantity quantity)
     (update item :quantity - quantity)]
    [item]))

(defn split-items [items quantities]
  (vec (mapcat #(split-item % (quantities (:line-no %))) items)))
```

```clj
(def items
  [{:name "Bananas", :line-no 0, :quantity 4}
   {:name "Apple",   :line-no 2, :quantity 3}])

(def return-quantities
  {2 1})

(split-items items return-quantities)
=> [{:name "Bananas", :line-no 0, :quantity 4}
    {:name "Apple",   :line-no 2, :quantity 1, :returned? true}
    {:name "Apple",   :line-no 2, :quantity 2}]
```

Comment: One more doubt, in the split-item function how do i append based on a condition ?


 (defn ^:private split-item
[item return-qty]
(If return-qty
   [(assoc item  :return-line? true :quantity return-qty)
      (when (pos? (- (:quantity item) return-qty)) (update item :quantity - return-qty))]
    [item]))

The above code results in null elements getting added. Then i will have to explicitly remove null elements by (vec (remove nil? ()) . Is there a better way to avoid adding null elements ?

Comment: To add no elements, simply return an empty collection (e.g. `[]`) rather than `nil`. `mapcat` concats the results of the mapping, and concat of an empty collection has no effect on the result.

Comment: Update: After a REPL experiment, I discovered it is safe to return `nil`, as that too will add no elements to the result.

Answer (score 0):

```clj
(def items [{:name “Bananas”
             :line-no 0
             :quantity 4}
            {:name “Apple”
             :line-no 2
             :quantity 3}])

(def return-quantities
  {0 3
   2 1})
```

```clj
(defn add-return [items-by-line-no line-no return-quantity]
  (let [item (first (get items-by-line-no line-no))
        item-decreased (update item :quantity - return-quantity)
        item-returned (assoc item :quantity return-quantity :returned? true)]
    (update items-by-line-no line-no #(conj (assoc % 0 item-decreased) item-returned))))

(pprint (reduce-kv add-return (group-by :line-no items) return-quantities))
;; {0
;;  [{:name "Bananas", :line-no 0, :quantity 1}
;;   {:name "Bananas", :line-no 0, :quantity 3, :returned? true}],
;;  2
;;  [{:name "Apple", :line-no 2, :quantity 2}
;;   {:name "Apple", :line-no 2, :quantity 1, :returned? true}]}
```